# How to run .Net Core 2.0 app as root?

Tags: .net-core

I have done a "dotnet publish -r linux-arm" to build a .NET Core 2.0 console application named TestSerialCommunication for a Raspberry PI. Then I copied the publish directory over to the Raspberry PI and the code runs. But, the code needs access to a serial port so in order to test this I need to run it as root.

I have tried the following:

```
$ cd publish
$ TestSerialCommunication
-bash: TestSerialCommunication: command not found
$ ./TestSerialCommunication
-bash: ./TestSerialCommunication: Permission denied
```

1) Why does these two commands behave differently? I thought that "./" was only the current directory.

Then I tried to run as a root:

```
$ sudo ./TestSerialCommunication
sudo: ./TestSerialCommunication: command not found
```

2) How do I correctly run the TestSerialComunication program as root?

Comment: Permission denied means the binary is not allowed to execute. Use `chmod a+x TestSerialCommunication` and then try again. 1) that's by design, and Linux binary without execute permission would lead to the same error message. 2) `sudo` is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It was in fact missing the execute permission. Do you know why the commands "TestSerialCommunication" and "./TestSerialCommunication" behaves differently?

Comment: That's purely the Linux convention. The former tries to locate a script or command registered, while the latter tries to execute a binary (I might not use the correct term, as I am not a Linux expert).

Comment: It looks like the executable attribute was lost during copy. can you try `chmod +x TestSerialCommunication` and then `./TestSerialCommunication` again?